# Show loader until page is fully loaded Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng2-admin

I am using ng2-admin theme for angular 2+. I am using API's to fetch data. The problem I am facing is that loader hides but data is still not loaded so the page first show skeleton of the page then load data. it looks odd.

I want the loader to show until all the data is rendered on the page.

First, I thought its the issue of API response but I see that API is completed it's just the browser rendering data which takes time.
For an idea, you can see in this example

```
this.loader = ture    
ApiCall.subscribe(response =>{
    logic();
    this.loader = false;
})
```

Loader gets hide but data is still rendering.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: add setTimeout around code who have the role to hide loader. to give some time to angular to digest request answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that two solution's are here.

1. If you have multiple callback function and want to get all data after all callback is completed, you use `Promise.all(iterable)` [Reference](http://www.gistia.com/mastering-promises/)
2. If you want to notify after view load, use `ngAfterViewInit` [Reference](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence)

**Edit**
Try to use this code

```
this.loader = true
ApiCall.subscribe(response => {
    logic();        
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.loader = false;
    }, 0);
});
```

I think both solution will help you.

Comment: Not the issue of the callback function. Callback functions are already processed but data is not displayed on the page. Event ngAfterViewInit function runs first then data gets displayed.

Comment: Its a problem all over the site. let me give you an idea. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
 this.loader = true;    
    ApiCall.subscribe(response =>{
        logic();
        setTimeout(() => { this.loader = false; })     
    })
```

So, it will only hide loader in the next tick(Change Detection Cycle);

Comment: I tried it but I have to provide time here. So sometimes data load early but the loader is running and sometimes timeout early but data is still not loaded. I need a way to control browser rendering data.

Comment: @YasirIjaz, you don't need to provide time. It will run immediately in the next run. Call it like example above.

Answer (score 0):

In your main app.component try

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if ((event) instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
   //   loader =true ;
    } else if ((event) instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
    // loader=false;
    }
});
```

It's better to write a common service for loader and use it like,
`this.loaderService.show();
 this.loaderService.hide();`